# JS json received with a decryption error on PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, post, xmlhttprequest

I sent a JSON string from Javascript and received it on PHP, however my PHP script is not receiving it as JSON.

The JS generates this output:

```
{"id_own":"Metztli Alonso","tick":"123456","ticket":"TID","comm":"test viernes nnuevo formato php","NQueues":"AMX-GI-Administracion-Interna","NCauses":"Capacitacion"}
```

But the PHP receives this:

```
id_own=Metztli+Alonso&tick=123456&ticket=TID&NQueues=AMX-GI-Administracion-Interna&NCauses=Capacitacion&comm=test+viernes+nnuevo+formato+php
```

JS

```js
//var obj = { id_own: f.id_own.value, tick: f.Ticket.value, ticket: TTYPE, comm: f.comments.value, NQueues: f.que.value, NCauses: f.cau.value };

//Sample data
var obj = { id_own: "Metztli Alonso", tick: "123456", ticket: "TID", comm: "test viernes nnuevo formato php", NQueues: "AMX-GI-Administracion-Interna", NCauses: "Capacitacion" };

const myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);

alert(myJSON);

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST","http://*****/dev_insert.php");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
xhr.send(myJSON);
```

PHP

```
<?php
echo "<br>";
echo "mensaje de js";
$requestPayload = file_get_contents("php://input");
var_dump ($requestPayload);
```

Comment: that's just URL-encoded - it's the standard way to transmit variables over HTTP (and has been around since long before JSON was standardised and widely-used). This is what PHP expects, and what it converts to an associative array which you can access as `$_POST`. So what is the actual problem?

Comment: Don't use `$requestPayload = file_get_contents("php://input");` It's grabbing the data without decoding it. Use `$_POST`. I have never heard of that method of getting post data before, very bizzare.

Comment: You can't use `$_POST` when data is being sent directly via a POST request. Using `php://input` is the correct approach. The fact that you're seeing it as a standard POST message suggests your Javascript isn't working the way it should. Check your console for errors and use your browser's network inspector to confirm how the request is being sent.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done much with JS, but should you be using `var` instead of `const`?

Comment: const would only be an issue if hes on an old browser that doesn't support it, the usage is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've provided, as it, won't do that.

The symptoms that you describe indicate that you are collecting the data from a form and running the JavaScript when the form is submitted, but not cancelling the default behaviour of the submit event.

Consequently:

1. The submit event fires
2. The JavaScript runs and initiates the Ajax request
3. The JavaScript finishes
4. The form submits … and URL encodes the data in it as you describe
5. The Ajax request is cancelled because the environment it is running in is going away
6. The browser renders the response to the form request

---

You need to prevent the default behaviour of the form submission:

```
form.addEventListener("submit", event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Then do everything you were already doing
});
```